# Endomorphism ring of $p$-adic integer $Z_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I would like to figure out the endomorphism ring of p-adic integer $Z_{p}$.

I know $End（Z）$ is isomorphic to $Z$,

And I guess $End（Zp）$ is also $Zp$.

My image : End$（Z_{p}）$$＝End（limZ/p^nZ）＝lim （End（Z/p^nZ））$$＝limZ/p^nZ＝$$Z_{p}$

My image might be wrong, I want to formally prove that the endomorphsm ring of $Zp$ is $Zp$.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z_p$ as abelian group, or as $\mathbb Z_p$-module?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, but I think as abelian group.

Comment: Isn't it a same thing? Every end of Zp as abelian grp can be seen as Zp mod and other direction is true? What is the difference between them?

Comment: For any ring $R$, every endomorphism of an $R$-module is also an endomorphism of it as abelian group. But in general, *not* every endomorphism as abelian group is an endomorphism as $R$-module. (Example: Take $R=\mathbb Z[i]$, the Gaussian integers. Then e.g. $h: a+bi \mapsto a-bi$ is an endomorphism as abelian group, but not as $\mathbb Z[i]$-mod because e.g. $h(i\cdot1) \neq i\cdot h(1)$.) -- Now in this special case of $R= \mathbb Z_p$, it happens to be true, but that needs to be proven, and that's exactly @BartMichels' answer to your comment under his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an inclusion $\mathbb Z_p \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb Z_p}(\mathbb Z_p)$, which sends $a$ to multiplication by $a$.

You are correct that this map is surjective: Let $f$ be an endomorphism and let $a = f(1)$. By $\mathbb Z_p$-linearity, we then have $f(b \cdot 1) = b \cdot f(1) = ab$ for all $b \in \mathbb Z_p$. Thus $f$ is multiplication by $a$.

The same proof works for any commutative ring (with 1): every $A$-module endomorphism of $A$ is multiplication by some $a \in A$.

Comment: For non-commutative rings, you might want to be a bit careful and have to use an opposite ring there.

Comment: Right, thanks. Edited.

Comment: What about as endomorphism ring as abelian group? That is my curiosity, sorry for my ambiguousness of notation.

Comment: @bellow Good question. Every group endomorphism of $\mathbb Z_p$ is automatically continuous, and this implies that it is still multiplication by a constant. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320339/endomorphisms-of-the-p-adic-group-mathbb-z-p